# FormControl valuechanges first input emits empty string

Tags: angular, pipe, form-control

```
private filtering(): void {
  this.filteredOptions$ = this.formC.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(800),
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
}
```

This function should give the Form Controls value to this._filter function. But on first input it gives empty string so it doesn't filter anything.

Cant just figure out why..

Comment: You do have a `startWith('')` operator. The observable will emit it first before emitting any other notifications.

Comment: @MichaelD isnt startwith required for this type of valueChange pipe?

Comment: not necessarily, what exactly are you trying to achieve with `startWith`?

Comment: @GuerricP if i remove startWith, then on first input it doesnt even go to this._filter function. So not sure how to get around this.

Comment: that means `this.formC.valueChanges` does not emit anything. Are you sure about the mapping between TypeScript and HTML?

Comment: are you trying to say that the first user keystroke in the field `formC` gives an empty string

Answer (score 1):

If we want to get an actual value on subscribing, we can emit it by self.

**Try this:**

```
  this.filteredOptions$ = defer(() =>
      this.formC.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.formC.value))
    ).pipe(debounceTime(800),map(value => this._filter(value)))
```

Comment: This is the one that worked! Thank you. :) If i understood defer correctly, it waits until there is a subscribtion and then proceeds?

Answer (score 0):

[`startWith`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith) is not a filtering operator, it returns a new `Observable` which emits an event in the very first place (empty string in your case), then emits events from the previous `Observable`.

Hard to say without details, but I think what you want to do is:

```
this.filteredOptions$ = this.formC.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(800),
    filter(this._filter)
);
```

Also, if `this.formC.valueChanges` does not emit anything, you probably have a problem with the mapping between the TypeScript `FormControl` and the corresponding HTML template

Answer (score 0):

The `debounceTime(800)` operator might restrict the user input. Try to do it without it

```js
private filtering(): void {
  this.filteredOptions$ = this.formC.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(value => this._filter(value))
  );
}
```